# How to make sure interrupt is delayed until "sleep for interrupt" is issued?

Tags: interrupt, microcontroller

Imagine the following scenario. A microcontroller is slave on a bus, say SPI. Once writing a byte on the bus, it wants to sleep until the byte is transferred. The code would look something like this:

```
write_byte_to_bus(byte);
wait_for_interrupt(); /* a single assembly instruction */
```

Now since the microcontroller is not the master, theoretically (and likely if the bus is really fast), the byte could be transferred immediately as the master requests and therefore something like this happens:

```
write_byte_to_bus(byte);
                                          interrupt arrives saying
                                          that operations is done
wait_for_interrupt();
```

which results in the microcontroller sleeping for interrupt after the interrupt has arrived. How can one protect itself from such cases?

Comment: Do you have a specific microcontroller in mind? This seems like the sort of situation that must have workarounds, but they may be controller specific.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I'm working currently with an STM8S, but I think such a problem arises with any microcontroller. It's a logical problem. It would be quite unamusing if every microcontroller would have to have a different solution for it.

Comment: Could you not issue a `SIM` before `write_byte_to_bus`. `WFI` will then re-enable interrupts.

Comment: What does wait_for_interrupt() do?  Is it an infinite loop or does it put the microcontroller in a low power state, or does it enable the interrupt?

Comment: @kkrambo, it puts the microcontroller in low power mode and wakes it up on interrupt.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, that's absolutely correct. I hadn't noticed that `WFI` automatically enables interrupts!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, if you write that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific microcontroller, you can disable interrupts first with a `SIM`, then execute your `write_byte_to_bus` and then `WFI` will re-enable interrupts appropriately.

Other microcontrollers may have different ways of managing this.